# How can you remove the need to type the full name of an .exe in cmd to run it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

OK, so you can run something like

```
start iexplore
```

in cmd and have it run internet explorer.

Is there a way to allow the same sort of behavior with something like, `javac.exe` (or some other utility exe)?

I don't want to have to type

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\javac.exe"
```

to run `javac` every time I need to via CL.

Comment: how about creating batch then all you need to do is double click.

Comment: Add it to your PATH. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html#path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should simply add "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\;" to the PATH environment variable.

To do this go to Control Panel > System and security > System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables and there scroll to "PATH" variable and Edit it adding "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\;" at the beginning.

As a final tip: I think you may also find useful a pair of answers to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358265/how-to-update-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd-windows).

Comment: If it is a common command I give it a unique variable. Then call it with %MYCMD% this avoids your path getting cluttered (decreasing the chance of duplicate exes too)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer making a custom script for adding environmental variables like the one mentioned by danicotra. Manually adding (and remembering) them after a reinstallation, setting up a a new computer, etc.. can be pretty annoying. Especially when your custom EnVar paths get bigger and start including more tools. ie: more than one programming language or custom CLI tools gathered over time.

You can save the following as a `.bat` file and execute for automatically adding custom paths to the existing EnVars. Needs Admin privileges.

```
:: Set Path variable equal to existing path plus specified directory.
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\;" /m

:: Add Custom path to existing envars
setx JAVA_PATH "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\;" /m
```